# "Can't insert values into my databse's table from UI"

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Values are not inserting in table login even though the query's response is showing "inserted" but table is not updated with the new row.

```
var mysql = require('mysql')

router.get('/save',function(req,res){
  var uname = req.query.username;
  var em = req.query.email;
  var pass = req.query.pass;
  var gender = req.query.gender;
  var dob = req.query.date;

  var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host:"localhost",
    user:"root",
    password:"abcd1234",
    database:"nodedb"
  });
  con.query('insert into login(username, email, password, gender, DOB) 
 VALUES("' + uname + '","' + em + '","' + pass + '","' + gender + '","' + dob + '")',function(err,rows,fields){
    console.log(rows);
    res.send("inserted");
  });
  con.end();
});

module.exports = router;
```

result shows
"inserted"
although the values are not inserted in my table.

Comment: You're not checking the `err` parameter to see if there was an error.

Comment: You should use a parametrized query instead of concatenating variables into the query.

Comment: What does `console.log(rows)` show?

Comment: It shows undefined

Comment: Then you must be getting an error. You should have `if (err) throw err;`

Comment: throw err;
      ^

Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (C:\Users\sherry\Desktop\myFiles\ExpressProject\dataform\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (C:\Users\sherry\Desktop\myFiles\ExpressProject\dataform\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Handshake.js:123:18)

Comment: Sounds like the password is wrong.

Comment: i guess it's right

Comment: If it's right you wouldn't get that error.

Comment: Please add the error message to the question, not just a comment.

Answer (score -1):

```
var mysql = require('mysql')

router.get('/save',function(req,res){
  var uname = req.query.username;
  var em = req.query.email;
  var pass = req.query.pass;
  var gender = req.query.gender;
  var dob = req.query.date;

  var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host:"localhost",
    user:"root",
    password:"abcd1234",
    database:"nodedb"
  });

var sql = "INSERT INTO login (username, email, password, gender, DOB) VALUES ('" + uname + "'" + ',' + "'" +  em + "'" + ',' + "'" +  pass + "'" + ',' + "'" +  gender + "'" + ',' + "'" + dob + "')";
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("1 record inserted");
        console.log(result);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Try the code above....
**Note** sql keywords are written in capital letters.
By the way, using raw sql in nodejs is tiresome so its better that you try using an ORM some time

Comment: SQL is case-insensitive, it doesn't have to be written in capital letters. It's just a popular style.

Comment: He's getting an "Access denied" error. How does your answer fix that?

Comment: check the ```var sql``` in my code. That`s how you insert data in a table when you are not using an ORM in nodejs. She made a mistake by not inserting the ```""``` and ```'``` properly to separate the values in the sql.

Comment: The right way is to use placeholders and put the variables in a separate array parameter.

Comment: You should explain the quoting problem in the answer.

Comment: I don't see the quoting problem. I tried the string concatenation, and my result was `insert into login(username, email, password, gender, DOB) VALUES("user","foo@bar","passwd","M","1961-03-31")` which looks good.

Comment: You made syntax errors... eg: ```var a = "' //bad```

Comment: I didn't write the question.

Comment: I copied her string into the browser console, and that's the result I got.

Comment: @SherryJain Put the error messages in the question, not comments!